# Data Type for TimeZone

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to keep the TimeZone of each City in My database. What would be the best data Type to use?

Table will have **CityID, CityName and TimeZone**

The reason I am keeping TimeZone value is because, when I am schedling event for a user then my program has to calculate new time based on the the Citry TimeZone

Comment: There is no specific data type for timezones. You likely, however, want 2 columns; the name (in a `varchar`) and the offset (in an `int`). At best, this is an opinionated answer though.

Comment: For other readers/answerers, what version of SQL server do you use? As SQL server 2016 adds `AT TIME ZONE` capabilities that could potentially be of use to you here. Perhaps you could include which version of SQL server you're using in your post.

Comment: I also ask, because storing certain timezone offsets is not necessarily your answer if the city recognizes DST and the above feature could help with that.

Comment: @Larnu Time zones are more complicated than one or two offsets, so I do not recommend storing this in the database for use in calculations. Offsets can change over time, cities can change which time zone they're in, etc., so I recommend delegating this to a library that handles all this for you.

Comment: I don't disagree, @StephenJennings , but you can't store a library in a database... But like I said, that doesn't change my point that this is likely opinated at best

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a specific data type for time zones. The time zone name is just a string, so VARCHAR(100) would be sufficient. If you want to normalize this, you could have a separate time zone table:

```
CREATE TABLE TimeZones (
   Id     INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)  -- your favorite primary key type
  ,Name   VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)
```

Then store the TimeZoneId in your Cities table.

The Name column would store either [Windows time zone identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-time-zones) ("Pacific Standard Time", etc.), or [tz database identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) ("America/Los_Angeles"), depending on what makes sense for your application. Or you could store both.

Time zones are more complicated than "an offset from UTC, plus sometimes a different offset during daylight saving time", so I do not recommend storing offsets in the database.